# Rails 4.1 nested routes redirect_to test won't pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, rspec, nested-routes

Just getting comfortable with Rails but this one has stumped me.  Thanks for the help!

Here is the current failing test.

```
Failures:

  1) SectionsController POST #create with valid attributes redirects to course_section_path
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to course_section_path
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"sections"} missing required keys:  [:course_id, :id]
     # ./spec/controllers/sections_controller_spec.rb:59:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.12643 seconds (files took 1.77 seconds to load)
```

Iv'e tried so many things to provide the redirect with the proper params but nothings seems to work.  Help!!  Thank you!

Rspec Test

```
  it "redirects to course_section_path" do
        post :create, section: attributes_for(:section)
        expect(response).to redirect_to course_section_path
  end
```

controller:  sections#show, section#create, and strong paramaters.

```
def create
    @section = Section.new(section_params)
    if @section.save 
        flash[:success]="New section added!"
        redirect_to course_section_path(@section.course_id, @section.id)
    else
        flash[:error] = "There was an error creating the section."
        render action: :new
    end
end

def show 
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @section = @course.sections.find(params[:id])
end

private

def section_params
    params.require(:section).permit(:name, :course_id)
end
```

Factory

```
factory :section do
    name "Section One"
    course_id 1
end
```

Database Scheema

```
  create_table "courses", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "sections", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "course_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Routes

```
  resources :courses
  resources :sections

  resources :courses do
    resources :sections
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured this one out!

The line

```
post :create, section: attributes_for(:section)
```

creates a record in the database, which when assigned to a variable, can be used to test with.

```
section = Section.last
```

Then going with what Szymon Borucki said, I provided the course_id and the Id needed to call the route.

```
expect(response).to redirect_to course_section_path(course_id: section.course_id, id: section.id)
```

AND it works!!

Here is the whole working test!

```
it "redirects to course_section_path" do
        post :create, section: attributes_for(:section)
        section = Section.last
        expect(response).to redirect_to course_section_path(course_id: section.course_id, id: section.id)
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Because 'sections' is a nested resource within 'courses', you need to provide course_id and section_id params with the path course_section_path. Try something like this:

```
  it "redirects to course_section_path" do
        course = create(:course) #if you use Factories
        post :create, section: attributes_for(:section)
        expect(response).to redirect_to course_section_path(course_id: course.id, id: section.id)
  end
```

Comment: Ok ya, I was trying something like that, but i keep getting - NameError:   undefined local variable or method `section'

Comment: BTW, I think you can get rid of "  resources :courses resources :sections" because you already declared them as nested resource. So, your route would be like this:  resources :courses do
    resources :sections
  end